# ffmpeg amix filter on mp3 with image

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to concatenate 2 mp3 files with amix filter (see full log).

It works fine for mp3 files without any meta but it fails with mp3 files with cover image in meta, result file length is less then 1 second.

How could I fix it in same command?

Here is full log:

```
localhost:Music user$ ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i /opt/docker/tag_long.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest,volume=2 -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 5  out.mp3 -report
ffmpeg started on 2018-11-11 at 13:19:50
Report written to "ffmpeg-20181111-131950.log"
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fe506000000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'input.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Paul
    album           : Underground Vol. 17
    title           : Crazy
    track           : 11/20
    date            : 2017
  Duration: 00:04:46.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
[mp3 @ 0x7fe50601aa00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from '/opt/docker/tag_long.mp3':
  Metadata:
    genre           : Blues
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c140 79.160302, 2017/03/02-16:59:38        ">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf
  Duration: 00:06:35.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
File 'out.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  volume (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7fe506045000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mp3 @ 0x7fe507810000] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, mp3, to 'out.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TPE1            : Paul
    TALB            : Underground Vol. 17
    TIT2            : Crazy
    TRCK            : 11/20
    TDRC            : 2017
    TSSE            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libmp3lame
    Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgb24(progressive), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=     496kB time=00:00:00.26 bitrate=15501.4kbits/s speed=0.336x    
video:495kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.084876%
```

Comment: Add `-c:v copy`

Comment: still not working

Comment: If you ever have more ffmpeg questions please copy and paste the complete log text instead of making image excerpts of the text.

Comment: Add -report to cmd and share report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fixed by adding `-vn` option

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering a bug that's already been fixed. FFmpeg development is very active, and this is an example why you should always try to use the most recent `ffmpeg` version that you can: especially when experiencing issues.

This amix hanging issue was fixed with [avfilter/af_amix: switch to activate](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=15e9c4afdc8efbf8da86bb3f7eaf374310b44bf8) on 2017-08-26. So use a version newer than that, such as the 3.4 release  branch or higher, or preferably a recent build from the git master branch.

See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to static builds of recent `ffmpeg` for Linux, macOS, and Windows. Alternatively, see the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) for compiling guides.

Comment: I use ffmpeg version 4.0.3-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.2.0-9) It's quite new, isn't it?

Comment: and with latest version it is not stucking but result mp3 file is less that 1 second length

Comment: @cutoffurmind Your truncated log output indicated that you may be using the 3.3 release branch. I need to see your new command and the complete log to provide any additional suggestions. Don't use `-report` unless you don't know how to copy and paste because it's too verbose.

Comment: ok I've updated question, see full log. On my computer I have ffmpeg 4.1 and on my production system 4.0.1 but it acts same on both systems

Comment: This is known bug. You will need to add -vn, do not encode cover image. You can add cover image later with -c copy/ without transcoding.